# Create a New Laravel Project Using Homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, laravel-5.4, homestead

I have already setup Laravel using homestead before, and I have an existing project that already works. However, i want to add another new project.

I have added a new folder and mapped it in the **homestead.yaml** file. But I want to know how to **setup the project itself** because the folder is empty and all the documentation I found is on the new site mapping. How about the new site configuration and files.

Please assist me in this as i am very new to Laravel. I am using Windows by the way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install Laravel using composer:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Alternative:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

and then `laravel new blog`
(make sure composer is in your path)

Comment: Where do we run this command? Inside `vagrant ssh`, then what path?

Comment: @AlvinTheodora you can run this anywhere you want to create the project. For use with Homestead, you usually map a folder like: ~/Desktop/Projects to /home/vagrant/projects and then do `laravel new blog` in ~/Desktop/Projects

Answer (score 1):

The mappings are installed only at the creation of virtual machine.
To refresh them run the machine with `homestead up --provision`